# why my AWS instance has different AMI than new instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a running instance that has

AMI ID ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20150325 ami-5189a661

When I go to page to launch new instance, I see a different AMI

Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-9abea4fb

so what are the differences ami-9abea4fb vs ami-5189a661 ?

I am running a t2.micro . When I a m ready to upgrade to t2.large, from what I read, I have to

1. stop the running instance (*ami-5189a661*)
2. detach the EBS
3. create a new instance (*ami-9abea4fv*) and attach the EBS to new instance

is that correct ? will the new instance work because it has different AMI than my existing instance ?

Comment: Did you create an AMI at some point? Because a search for `ami-9abea4fv` doesn't turn up anything. I think that may be a private AMI in your account. In any case, this doesn't appear to be a programming question so it is probably off topic for this site. Also, why not going into the AMI list and **LOOK** at the AMIs to see what the difference is instead of coming here and asking us to look for you?

Comment: Regarding your second question, why do you feel the need to upgrade from one AMI to another? If you don't even know what the difference in the AMIs is, why "upgrade" from one to another? Also the procedure you listed won't do anything at all but change the instanceID of your instance. All the data from the AMI goes onto the EBS, so if you throw away the EBS and reuse your old EBS, you will have accomplished nothing.

Comment: you dont need to chage AMI to change instance size, just stop the instance then "change instance type" to t2.large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant `ami-9abea4fb` instead of `ami-9abea4fv`.

The names of these AMI images tells you want you want to know:

```
ami-9abea4fb: ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20150325
ami-5189a661: ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20160114.5
```

They are both Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but one was created in March of 2015, and the other was created in January of 2016.  The latter one has updates from the period between those two dates applied.  If you create two instances from each of those two images, and manually apply all the updates, they should be functionally identical.

Since these are EBS backed instances, you can upgrade it to `t2.large` by simply selecting Change Instance Type in the AWS Console.  There's no need to create a new instance with a new image.

Comment: The "Change Instance Type" is grayed out. Btw, are you saying that if I launch new instance with AMI January 2016, attach the same EBS, then do apt-get update , apt-get upgrade, I should get less number of components to upgrade ?

Comment: Your instance must be stopped to change the type.  Booting from the old EBS on a new instance should work too.  I don't think it makes any difference which image you use in that case.